# How to write conditional instantiation in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, default-constructor

I have a below lambda default `Employee` constructor which is working fine.

```
this.For<IEmployee>().Use(() => new Employee());
```

Now I want to call another another constructer based on `flag` value.
If `flag` is `true` call `Employee` constructor with parameter.
If `flag` is `false` call default constructor.

```
this.For<IEmployee>().Use(
if (flag)
{
    () => new Employee("Test");
}
else
{
    () => new Employee());
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
this.For<IEmployee>().Use(() => flag ? new Employee("Test") : new Employee());
```

Comment: Thanks I tried as above but it throwing this error" Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string'  because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: @ShakeerHussain, if your original `Use` works with a lambda expression, then this new lambda expression which has the same signature (`Func<Employee>`)  will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just have the syntax/structure mixed up.  This part of the lambda:

```
() =>
```

is the *function header*.  Everything after it is the function *body*.  You're trying to wrap your `if` structure around that.  Which would conceptually be similar to:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    public Employee SomeFunc() { return new Employee("Test"); }
}
else
{
    public Employee SomeFunc() { return new Employee(); }
}
```

As you can see, this isn't how to structure code.  Instead, move the logic to *within* the function body.  For example:

```
this.For<IEmployee>().Use(() => {
    if (flag)
    {
        return new Employee("Test");
    }
    else
    {
        return new Employee());
    }
});
```

(Which can be refactored to something more compact, but left here for the purpose of illustration.)